# Firefox print top alignment is not good in 2nd page

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height:9.5in;width:7in;position:relative;overflow:hidden;">
        <div style="position: absolute;left: 204px; top: 64px;">
            <h1>One</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="page-break-after: always"></div>
    <div style="height:9.5in;width:7in;position:relative;overflow:hidden;">
        <div style="position: absolute;left: 204px; top: 64px;">
            <h1>Two</h1>
        </div>
            <div style="position: absolute;left: 204px; top: 164px;">
            <h1>Three</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code displaying properly in brower, but in print/print-preview in firefox, the 2nd page css top is not working. Both the words "Two" and "Three" overwritten. Please help me to align it properly.
[image]

Comment: inline styling?  check out http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml  for setting up print stylesheets

Answer (score 0):

There is a tricky print-rendering bug in Firefox that causes this behavior. The top margin of the 2nd (or more) printed page in Firefox is 1px too high. Being inside what I will call the "y-pos dead zone" the y-positioning of elements is ignored, thus causing the text "Two" and "Three" to render on top of each other as if they both had the css definition top:0px.

The easiest fix/hack is to add a margin-top:1px onto any page past the first.

If you want a better visualization of this problem add a border onto the absolutely positioned divs.

(If you want some insight into how Firefox is doing the rendering try setting a negative margin-top:-80px which will still have the rendering bug. But if you go up to -85px suddenly the bug goes away. This begins to show that the bug has something to do with how Firefox is trying to render around the gutter between pages.)

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting all day with this bug until I found this Question, thx a lot! That pointed me to the right direction. The fix from purgatory101 did not work for me, but at least I could see, that FF is not capable to print anything with absolute position. We changed it to relative and now it seems to work. There is still a bug, that when it comes out of the printer, it is moved to the right a bit (the preview is ok, the papers not), but this is a big success for me.

So my solution: put everything you need positioning to a div wrapper with absolute positioning and inside you can put relative divs with the same coordinates as you used earlier.

```
<div style="position: absolute;">
       <div style="position: relative; top: ...">
             blah
       </div>
       <div style="position: relative; top: ...">
             bleh
       </div>
</div>
```

**Update**: I realized that IE sufferfs with similar bugg - all absolute positioned elements loose the css styles from the 2nd page (eg. z-index or opacity), but at least they stay on right coordinates. Just chrome seems to me now doing everything right.